# how to make background image responsive?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I wanna know how I can make the div's background responsive

My code:

```
    height:500px;
    background-image: url(../images/Doctor.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
```

The result:

[image: image 1]

When i zoom out :

[image: image2]

The problem is when I zoom in or out I want the doctor image fixed in zoom not in scroll

Comment: can you share your html code as well?

Comment: Read about static backgrounds in a HTML Tutorial

Comment: It looks like you're scrolling in your screenshots. You're not looking for [background-attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) are you?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it responsive, try the following snippet. Do not set width, height, or margins.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/394/screenshots/196178/attachments/3368/background-circles.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
}

span {
  color: tomato;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span>Responsive Background<br/>Image</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    height: auto;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/394/screenshots/196178/attachments/3368/background-circles.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
```